# Is best practice to Web Application users credentials using same database users credentials

Tags: database-design, credentials

**I have multiple Web applications using same database (MariaDB), so i want to using same user credentials as centralize, so:**

- Is it best practice to using same database users credentials and
  when add new user add the user also on the database with proper
  privilege ??
  **OR**
- create separate table for the users and the any transaction using
  only one database user to connect, insert, delete, update, ....
  Thanks & Regards.

Comment: There's no "best practice" -- your authentication and authorization mechanisms should be driven by your business and security requirements. If you explain what they are, someone might be able to suggest a concrete solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to use database usernames to authenticate web application users, but that is rather uncommon.

End users are typically authenticated at the **enterprise** level - meaning they use the **same identity** in a single-sign-on fashion to identify themselves with **multiple** enterprise applications.

Then in web applications, those identities are mapped to a small number of specific **database** users with capabilities matching the roles/profiles of the end users.

Having all enterprise users (and much less end users) defined in all databases becomes a logistic nightmare once the number exceeds a few ten's of users. It is definitely not possible once you start having end-users/customers accounts going rapidly into the millions.